# Disallow multiple votes on image on an angular list

Tags: angularjs

I have the following Angular and HTML code to display a list of images and allow voting:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var application = angular.module('Application', []);

  application.service('ImageService', function ($http) {

    return {

      GetList: function (page) {
        return $http.get('api/images', { params: { page: page } });
      },

      Vote: function (image) {
        return $http.post('api/images/{key}/vote', { key: image.Key });
      }

    }

  });

  application.controller('ImageController', function ImageController($scope, ImageService) {

    var page = 0;
    $scope.images = [];

    ImageService.GetList(page)
      .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.images = $scope.images.concat(data);
      })
      .error(function (data, status, headers, config) { });

    $scope.vote = function (image) {
      ImageService.Vote(image)
         .success(function (data, status, headers, config) { })
         .error(function (data, status, headers, config) { });
    };

  });

</script>

<div data-ng-app="Application" data-ng-controller="ImageController" class="gallery">
  <div data-ng-repeat='image in images' class="image">
    <img src="{{image.Url}}" alt="" />
    <a href="" data-ng-click="vote(image)"><i class="icon-heart"></i></a>
   <span>{{image.Votes}}</span>
  </div>      
</div>
```

Each image has an unique id, image.Id.

How can I disallow a user to vote the same image twice?

Comment: The only way to prevent it would be to prevent it in the backend.

Comment: Yes, sure. But in this case I do not mind that a user might vote twice in two different requests. I would just like to disallow the user to vote in the same request. This is because most of the time the images will always be different

Comment: that's not clear from the question

Comment: I remember this code. :)

Comment: @Shomz Yep, I am around this code for a few days. I am learning Angular. It is really great ... I am not sure if it is a full replacement for JQuery but for communication with an API it is great.

Comment: It's not a replacement for jQuery, but is **much much** more than it. You'll see it yourself soon. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use ng-hide to hide link if hasVoted is true.

```
<div class="gallery">
  <div data-ng-repeat='image in images' class="image">
    <img src="{{image.Url}}" alt="" />
    <a href="" data-ng-hide="image.hasVoted" data-ng-click="vote(image)"><i class="icon-heart"></i></a>
   <span>{{image.Votes}}</span>
  </div>      
</div>
```

Then modify controller to set voted to true. If it fails we will set it back to false. The reason to do it is to prevent multiple clicks on the button until we receive success back from the server:

```
$scope.vote = function (image) {
  image.hasVoted = true;
  ImageService.Vote(image)
     .success(function (data, status, headers, config) { })
     .error(function (data, status, headers, config) { image.hasVoted = false; });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest tweak on the client side would be something like this:

```
$scope.vote = function (image) {
  if (!image.voted) {
    ImageService.Vote(image)
     .success(function (data, status, headers, config) { image.voted = true })
     .error(function (data, status, headers, config) { });
  }
};
```

Simply flag the image as voted.